# Selenium GRID : org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to create new service: ChromeDriverService

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-grid

This is my code and i was not able to create a node, and it throws Exception as FAILED: runtest
org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to create new service: ChromeDriverService. I have tried with same machine and different machine, still the problem exist. as i am new to Grid i was not able to sort out.

```
 public class Gridtest1 {
        WebDriver driver;
        DesiredCapabilities cap;
        @Test
        public void runtest() throws MalformedURLException {         System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","D:\\Selenium_Grid\\chromedriver.exe");
             cap = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
            URL url = new URL("http://192.168.0.107:4444/wd/hub");
            //URL url = new URL("http://192.168.0.107:5556");
            ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
            driver = new RemoteWebDriver(url, options);
            //driver=new ChromeDriver();
            driver.get("http://google.com/");
            System.out.println("Title is " + driver.getTitle());
            driver.close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is Grid console is displaying for you? You can check the Grid status(nodes attached) here: http://192.168.0.107:4444/console

Comment: you probably have to update the driver

Comment: Yes @Magesh grid console shows the attached node and the cmd also shows the node attached

Comment: @NicholasAlbion I tried updating the latest Driver still the problem exists

Answer (score 2):

you need to set path for driver in **command prompt**:-

```
java -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver="full path of your driver" -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.12.0.jar -role node -hub http://ip of host machine:4444/grid/register
```

Once you set that, run your code, in my case code was like this:

```
DesiredCapabilities desCap = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();      
WebDriver remoteWebDriver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("your ip address/wd/hub"), desCap);
remoteWebDriver.get("your url");
```

this worked for me.

Comment: Could you explain how the command 'java -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver="full path of your driver" -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.12.0.jar -role node -hub http://ip of host machine:4444/grid/register' resolves the issue?

Answer (score 0):

For remote driver you don't need the line of `setProperty`. Please try with create the driver with capabilities.

```
DesiredCapabilities cap = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
cap.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY,options);
RemoteWebDriver driver= new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://localhost:4444/wd/hub/"), cap);
```